# Not able to fetch the connections from the connection API

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am developing an APP to get the connections of a user. Unfortunately when I am using the connection API then I am getting the error

> "Access to connections denied".

I have checked the scope setting, getting no option there to add/remove the options. Sharing the available options which are enabled on my application by-default.

```
r_emailaddress (3-legged member permission)
w_share (3-legged member permission)
r_basicprofile (3-legged member permission)
r_liteprofile (3-legged member permission)
rw_company_admin (3-legged member permission)
w_member_social (3-legged member permission)
```

I have also requested the `r_fullprofile` access & registered with the partner program to get access of `r_1st_connections` & rest access but no one from Linkedin responded on this request.

**If required I can share my postman collection.**
Checking the API Via Postman

```
GET: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&projection=(elements*(to~(id,localizedFirstName,localizedLastName)))

Header
authorization Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Connection Keep-Alive
O/P:{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections",
    "status": 403
}
```

With the same header I was able to fetch the basic profile details
`GET: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`

Comment: For clarification on the OAuth, are whose connections are you trying to browse? This API endpoint requires a member to enter their own account credential to view their own 1st degree connections. You can't view the connections of other users.

Comment: @Pratibha Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @kartiraman need register to the program then after we can access.